# How To Create Feature Discovery Using Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, feature-discovery

I want to create a tutorial page after launching the app to give the user an overview of the features in the application and how to use it.

For example the tutorial page ↓ in [anydesk app](https://anydesk.com/en/downloads/android)

[image]

**So, How to create this page using XF?**

**What is the term or key should i use to find examples about this on google such as "Onboarding Pages"?**

## Update

I have [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62914352/4977870) to add this [feature](https://material.io/archive/guidelines/growth-communications/feature-discovery.html#feature-discovery-design) on android and it's working fine

**Now The question is How to do that on Ios?**

Comment: You can display a layout with opacity < 1 above the original layout in the same view/page.

Comment: @AnasAlweish I can show you an example in `Xamarin forms` from one of my projects but it is not for android, it is for Tizen (Samsung smartwatch OS). it is almost similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading many resources, I ended up using [**Custom Renderers**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/)

> **In the Shared Project**

**1- [Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view#creating-the-custom-control) a Xamarin.Forms custom control.**

```
public class FeatureDiscoveryTarget : View
{
    public Element Target { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class FeatureDiscoverySequence : View
{
    public IList<FeatureDiscoveryTarget> Targets { get; }
    public Action ShowAction { get; set; }
    public FeatureDiscoverySequence()
    {
        Targets = new List<FeatureDiscoveryTarget>();
    }
    public void ShowFeatures()
    {
        ShowAction?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

**2- [Consuming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view#consuming-the-custom-control) the Custom Control from Xamarin.Forms.**

**.XAML**

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="3">
  
    <Button x:Name="BtnTest" Text="Test Feature Discovery" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>

    <Button x:Name="Btn1" Text="Feature 1"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
    
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Button x:Name="Btn2" Text="Feature 2"  />
        <Button x:Name="Btn3" Text="Feature 3" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"  />
    </StackLayout>
   
    <Button x:Name="Btn4" Text="Feature 4" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  />

    <local:FeatureDiscoverySequence x:Name="TapTargetSequence">
        <local:FeatureDiscoverySequence.Targets>
            <local:FeatureDiscoveryTarget Target="{x:Reference Name=Btn1}" Title="Feature 1" Description="Details.... " />
            <local:FeatureDiscoveryTarget Target="{x:Reference Name=Btn2}" Title="Feature 2" Description="Details.... " />
            <local:FeatureDiscoveryTarget Target="{x:Reference Name=Btn3}" Title="Feature 3" Description="Details.... " />
            <local:FeatureDiscoveryTarget Target="{x:Reference Name=Btn4}" Title="Feature 4" Description="Details.... " />
        </local:FeatureDiscoverySequence.Targets>
    </local:FeatureDiscoverySequence>

</StackLayout>
```

**.Cs**

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TapTargetSequence.ShowFeatures();
    }
```

> **In Android Project**

**1- Add this [library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.TapTargetView) to android project only**

**2- Create a new instance of MainActivity Class**

```
public static MainActivity Instance { get; private set; }

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
     // ... 
     LoadApplication(new App());
     Instance = this;
 }
```

**3- [Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view#creating-the-custom-renderer-on-each-platform) the custom renderer for the control.**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Content;
using View = Android.Views.View;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Com.Getkeepsafe.Taptargetview;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Color = Android.Resource.Color;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(FeatureDiscoverySequence), typeof(SequenceRenderer))]

namespace YourNameSpace.Droid
{
    class SequenceRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.ViewRenderer<FeatureDiscoverySequence, View>
    {
        public SequenceRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<FeatureDiscoverySequence> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            e.NewElement.ShowAction = new Action(ShowFeatures);
        }
        private void ShowFeatures()
        {
            var targets = new List<Com.Getkeepsafe.Taptargetview.TapTarget>();
            foreach (var target in Element.Targets)
            {
                var formsView = target.Target;
                string title = target.Title;
                string description = target.Description;

                var renderer = Platform.GetRenderer((Xamarin.Forms.View) formsView);

                var property = renderer?.GetType().GetProperty("Control");

                var targetView = (property != null) ? (View) property.GetValue(renderer) : renderer?.View;

                if (targetView != null)
                {
                    targets.Add
                    (
                        TapTarget
                            .ForView(targetView, title, description)
                            .DescriptionTextColor(Color.White)
                            .DimColor(Color.HoloBlueLight)
                            .TitleTextColor(Color.Black)
                            .TransparentTarget(true)
                            .TargetRadius(75)
                    );
                }
            }
            new TapTargetSequence(MainActivity.Instance).Targets(targets).Start();
        }
    }
}
```

> **In Ios Project ...Todo**

> ### [The Result on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2wuW.gif)

**For More Information**

1. [For Android](https://material.io/archive/guidelines/growth-communications/feature-discovery.html#)
2. [For IOS](https://material.io/develop/ios/components/feature-highlights/)
3. [KeepSafe/TapTargetView Github](https://github.com/KeepSafe/TapTargetView)
4. [Xamarin.Forms Custom Renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/)

Comment: Did you get for iOS ?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this effect with a simple approach.
Use 2 layouts the first is the original view and the other,
 nested inside the first layout (with `Opacity` < 1) is the tutorial page.

**.XAML:**

```
    <ContentPage.Content>

      
        <!--THIS IS THE LAYOUT FROM BEHIND-->
        <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="mainLayout">
          
            <!--Controls...-->

          
            <!--THIS CAN BE THE TUTORIAL PAGE, SEE THE OPACITY-->
            <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="tutorialLayout" IsVisible="true" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, [total width], [total height]" Opacity="0.8">
                        <!--Controls...-->
            </AbsoluteLayout>

        </AbsoluteLayout>


    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer
I have tried the solution but it did not give me the result that [I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2wuW.gif)